# Paypal Documentation Confusing

Tags: python, paypal

I'm setting up a web checkout with python.

[here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/) the return url shows the variable as `"PayerID"`
but [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/web-checkout/) it shows it as `"Payer-ID"`

Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1). **Accept a PayPal payment** https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/

> When the user approves the payment, PayPal redirects the user to the
>   return_url that was specified
>
> when the payment was created. A payer Id and payment Id are appended
>   to the return URL, as PayerID and paymentId:
>
> http://return_url?paymentId=PAY-6RV70583SB702805EKEYSZ6Y&token=EC-60U79048BN7719609&PayerID=7E7MGXCWTTKK2

2). **Accept PayPal with the Payments API** https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/web-checkout/

```
payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment.find("Payment-ID")
payment.execute({"payer_id": "Payer-ID "})
```

> Note the HATEOAS links in the example response above. Direct the user
>   to the approval_url on the PayPal site, so that the user can approve
>   the payment. PayPal then redirects the user to the return_url that was
>   specified when the payment was created. A payer ID is appended to the
>   return URL, as Payer-ID.

Comment: You re stating the answer helped me realized I needed to test it.  For the record I'm using option 2, but it returns option 1 ```PayerId```